# Custom redactor.css file

Tags: richtext, redactor

I would like to override or include a custom redactor.css file so that I can match the typography of the rich text editor contents with the site's stylesheet.

The path to redactor.css is hard-coded into the application (craft/app/fieldtypes/RichTextFieldType.php - line 281), and obviously I don't want to change this file or the redactor.css file.

Is there at least a way to inject a custom css file into the admin pages so that the core/base styles can be overridden?

---

UPDATE: Both plugin solutions below worked, but because craft includes redactor.css *after* the plugin's css include is inserted, the trick is to make your css selectors more specific, i.e.:

```
.redactor_.redactor_editor h1 { font-size: 48px !important; }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can override the control panel's CSS with a plugin. Use the popular ["Control Panel CSS plugin"](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) by Lindsey DiLoreto or make your own little one.

Make use of the [`includeCssResource()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#includeCssResource-detail) function and include a CSS file with your custom redactor styles:

myRedactorCssPlugin.php:

```
public function init()
{
    if (craft()->request->isCpRequest())
    {
        craft()->templates->includeCssResource('myRedactorCss/redactor.css');
    }
}
```

resources/redactor.css:

```
.redactor_editor h1 {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
.redactor_editor p {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: The plugin worked fairly well, except that it inlcudes the css file _before_ the redactor.css file is included, and redactor.css contains a ton of !important declarations, so things like h1 font-size cannot be overridden.  Frustrating....

Comment: I solved the !important issue by making a more specific css selector:  instead of redactor_editor h1 {}, I used .redactor_.redactor_editor h1 {} along with lots of !important's.

Comment: You could even make it more specific by chaining the same class with itself: `.btn.btn {}`, @monkeyArms ;)

Comment: How did I not know you could do that!?  I learned some things today.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [RedactorStyles](https://github.com/aelvan/RedactorStyles-Craft/) plugin, and set the `Styles Css` field (for inline CSS), or `Styles Css File` field (for CSS in a file). It's worked great for me.

Comment: This worked as well, but suffers from the same issue as the "Control Panel CSS plugin":  Craft includes the redactor.css file after the plugin's css include, so the !important attributes cannot be overridden.